# Basic custom template variables

Tags: entities, 8

I am a web designer with development experience. I have been using Wordpress and have felt comfortable editing php files and playing with functions. On the tip of an acquaintance I decided to try Drupal despite the more advanced coding level required  & steep learning curve. I am amazed at the level of customization in the admin and excited about things like twig.

However I am having trouble understanding how to get custom variables from fields to work in a template. The theme packaged with Drupal 8 (Stark) seems to apply them automatically. But when I research how to do it (a ton of research) it seems like each group of custom fields need a function declared. Is this the only way? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: "field" is a loaded term in Drupal. A **F**ield is similar to Wordpress CCK, which can be attached to **C**ontent. A form field or a render array field represents an element that is rendered on the page by a template (or theme function). However is what you are researching about assigning a value to a Twig variable in a Twig template?

Comment: Yes. For example: If I create custom content called "Product" and I have a form field named "Product SKU", is the twig variable automatically generated for use in templates (eg, is it the machine name) or do I need to write a function to create said variable and associate it with the form field?

Comment: If you added a **F**ield to the Product content type, then you can manage how that Field is displayed in the node form (Form Display) or node view (Manage Displays). The UI in Drupal allows you to change the Field Widget (form array) that a Field uses, and change the Field Formatter (render array) that a Field uses. You should only need to set the field to use a field widget in Form Display for it to show up on the Node form

Comment: So how would I apply the variable to the template markup?

Comment: Does `<p>{{ product_sku }}</p>` work without any functions declaring the variable? (assuming that is the machine name)

Comment: I think I understand the question now: How can I print/render Fields on a Node in a Twig template?

Comment: Correct. Do I need to build the page first using nodes/content types and views or can I just write up a twig template with the variable "placeholders"? And is it correct that those variable names would be the machine name for the corresponding field?

Comment: Then, I think your answer is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/193718/42650 and in the question, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193717/render-node-fields-and-labels-in-node-template?rq=1